# sql update query for two connected tables

Tags: mysql, update

```
UPDATE rooms set r.vacant=true 
FROM reservation s,rooms r 
WHERE r.room_no = s.room_no AND s.cus_id=1
```

I created above sql queryto update room status.I want to set vacant as true when customer_id =1.
But this code didn't work on mysql.
Whats wrong with this?

Comment: Didn't work? Did you get an error?

Comment: Did you check mysql documentation about update syntax?

Comment: UPDATE x JOIN y ON ...SET..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an INNER JOIN statement:

```
UPDATE rooms r
INNER JOIN reservation s
ON s.room_no = r.room_no
SET r.vacant=true
WHERE s.cus_id=1
```